# previous and next button navigating page to first and last page in kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

```
$(selector).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: jsonData,
    rowTemplate: '#: Store_ID # #: Store_Name # #: Store_Address # #: Terminal_ID # #: Severity_Type ##: Error_Type ##: Error_Date # ',
    altRowTemplate: '#: Store_ID # #: Store_Name # #: Store_Address # #: Terminal_ID # #: Severity_Type ##: Error_Type ##: Error_Date # ',
    sortable: true,
    selectable: 'row',
    scrollable: false,
    pageable: {
        previousNext: true,

        pageSize: 5,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 2,

        messages: {

            display: "Showing {0}-{1} from {2} data items"
        }
    },
    //other properties...

});
```

I have four pages, but when I click on next button, it is navigating to fourth page directly from first page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changed your datasource up a bit to

    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: jsonData,
        pageSize: 5
      }),

And it seems to page just fine.  http://jsbin.com/uBUbuGuq/1/edit

Comment: @giltnerj0, you should post that as an answer (and add what was wrong with it to make it complete :) )

Answer (score 0):

Change your dataSource to a kendo.data.DataSource, and set the pageSize on it to what you want the default pagesize to be.

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: jsonData,
    pageSize: 5
  }),
```

Should work fine with that.  http://jsbin.com/uBUbuGuq/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. My issue got resolved. :)